# reference request: proof that group characters are a basis for $L^2$

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, reference-request, representation-theory, topological-groups

I know the following must be very standard, but I haven't found it in any of the functional analysis books to which I have access.  Do you know where I can find a self-contained proof?:

If $G$ is a compact Hausdorff abelian topological group, the set of characters (i.e. continuous homomorphisms $G \rightarrow S^1$) form a Hilbert basis for $L^2(G)$.

Comment: This is done in detail in "A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis" by Gerald Folland.

Comment: @N.U. Could you post an answer with basic steps of the proof?

Comment: @N.U. Thanks! I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: @Norbert I posted an answer with the basic steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Folland's book: Let $G$ be an abelian compact Hausdorff group with measure $\mu$ so that $\mu(G) = 1$.

(1) The set of characters, $\hat{G}$, is orthonormal: If $\xi \neq \eta$ are two characters, then there exists an $x_0 \in G$ such that $\xi \eta^{-1}(x_0) \neq 1$. By a change of variable and invariance of Haar measure,
$$
\int \xi \bar{\eta} = \xi \eta^{-1}(x_0) \int \xi \bar{\eta}
$$
so $\int \xi \bar{\eta} = 0$.

(2) The set is a basis: If $f \in L^2(G)$ is orthogonal to all characters, $\xi$, then
$$
0 = \int f \bar{\xi} = \hat{f}(\xi),
$$
so $f = 0$ by the Plancherel theorem. ($\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$).